# Getting Article topic/category from Readability API or somewhere else

Tags: objective-c

I am currently using the Readability Parser API in order to convert webpages to clean text (like reader mode in safari).

Looking through the options that the Parser API provides I see  "author", "content", "domain"... and more. What I can't find is topic or category.

I want to split up the articles based on there topic. For example something from ESPN would most likely be a "Sports" topic where something from Cult of the Mac would be "Technology".

I know that Flipboard(app) does this very well.

Is there anyway to determine the topic of the article either through readability or any other library/API/Method??